# How to add code to Magento shop with uDropship marketplace installed

Tags: magento-1.8

I have an installation of Magento community installed (v. 1.81). In this installation I have installed the uDropship Marketplace, which allows us to have multiple vendors on the site.

But my problem is, that I need some additional information on the different vendors that the module do not support out of the box. I need the vendors to be able to include their nationality and native VAT-rate (a special European sales tax rate).

How do I do this, the VAT/tax-rate is needed to calculate the products prices based on the specific vendor VAT rate. In other words, can I just add the fields in the Unirgy uDropship_vendor table or do I need to implement and consider std. Magento functionality as well?

I hope you are able to help me out - I do not hear back from Unirgy support, though they have been great on helping me out earlier..

Answer (score 1):

uDropship already provided solution for this.

Go to `Admin->Sales->Dropship->Vendor->(Select Any Vendor)->Custom Data`

Here You can add your data, in your case say VAT and TIN then

```
===== VAT =====
012345678
===== TIN =====
012345678
```

And this data is available on product template via using

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('udropship') ->getVendor($_product) ->getData('VAT');
echo Mage::helper('udropship') ->getVendor($_product) ->getData('TIN');
?>
```

You always find this data using vendor data

Comment: Hi @ganesh, thank you very much for replying. I am not sure that I understand you correctly.. But will I be able to register the VAT rate on the specific vendor (under custom data), and it will be stored so I can retrieve that value calculating product price incl. vendor VAT-rate? In other words it is important to me that if I have an order that represent maybe 5 different vendors with different products then I will need to add/calculate the incl. VAT price based on each vendor VAT-rate registered in "custom data"? Sorry I am not that technical :(..

Comment: This custom data field is for specific vendor, so if you have 5 product from 5 different vendor in order, then for each `$_product` when you try to print `echo Mage::helper('udropship') ->getVendor($_product) ->getData('VAT');`, you will get `VAT value` corresponding Vendor who own this product.